# RxDart - BehaviorSubject/Observable of type Void

Tags: dart, flutter, system.reactive

What's the best way to handle actions that trigger transformations in `RxDart`?

Scenarios:

- Send a request once the user taps a button.
- Request a new page in a list.

In other Reactive implementations like `RxSwift`, you can define the type `Observable<Void>` and listen to new events to start the transformations.

You can define a Observable in `RxDart` but then you are forced to add something in the subject like `subject.add('something')` or `subject.add(0)` which is confusing. It would be cool to use `subject.add(void)`, `subject.add()` or `subject.add(())` but this is not possible.

The first idea that comes to my mind is to create a new type like `Empty` or more specifically for the proposed scenarios `Action`.

Then I could do something like this:

```
PublishSubject<Action> action = PublishSubject<Action>();
action.withLatestFrom(...)
    .map(....) // Apply the desired transformations
    ....
    ....;
action.add(Action.create());
action.add(Action.create());
```

Am I reinventing the wheel?

Is there a simpler approach to handle elegantly what I am proposing here?

Comment: yes, you are right: `PublishSubject` is a way to follow - just call `add` method to send your data event to registered listeners

Comment: In Rx.Net we use Observable<Unit>, if there is no other data

Comment: Thanks @pskink. However, the question is about the data type. The other part is already solved.

Comment: use void - button does not pass any data

Comment: This is not allowed in RxDart, hence the question :)

Comment: you cannot use `PublishSubject<void>`? does it throw any exception?

Comment: Sure I can. But then I have to use `subject.add("something")` or `subject.add(0)` which is confusing. I'm after the most expressive and clean syntax here.

I've updated the question to make my point more clear.

Comment: or `subject.add(null)` but if you dont like such `null`s extend `PublishSubject<null>` and add `add()` method that would simply call `this.add(null)`

Comment: Not bad... That's interesting, but still not 100% convinced

Answer (score 0):

Are you tried something like `subject.add(Object())`?
`Object` instance is the best solution I found until now, I think and if there is not another better solution for now, I will continue working with it.

For example, for test it, you could write something like:

```
  test('my subject test', () {
    subject.listen((result) {
      expect(result, isInstanceOf<Object>());
    });
    // myButtonMethodToTestSubject();
  })
```

I'm building this [Github-flutter-notes-rxdart](https://github.com/jclemus91/flutter-notes-rxdart) application to continue learning RxDart on Flutter and I chose `Object` as in charge of send "void" data as you has been required

Tell if you found a better solution to your own `Action` type.

Comment: `Object` is good. I don't think is more expressive than `Action`. Do you think creating an own type like `Action` just to add more expressiveness doesn't worths it?